# Feeding Scanner.Bytes() to a channel in Go

Tags: go, concurrency

Please consider this script:
https://play.golang.org/p/o4ZhuB3GJ0s (important part below)

It's creating random(ish) strings that look like "foo|foo" (where "foo" is random, but repeated).

I read them with `Scanner.Bytes()` into an input channel, then 16 worker threads convert them to strings and put them into an output channel.

In the output channel, I split the strings on `|` to make sure both sides are the same (no data corruption).

Here's the part of the code that scans the input buffer:

```
// Send input into channel
go func() {
    // Normally os.Stdin
    s := bufio.NewScanner(simulatedStdin)
    start = time.Now()
    for s.Scan() {
        thisLine := s.Bytes()
        line := make([]byte, len(thisLine))
        // Copy the slice so it's not changed on the next iteration
        copy(line, thisLine)
        lines <- line

        // Works, but perhaps the least efficient way to do it
        // lines <- []byte(string(s.Bytes()))
        // lines <- []byte(s.Text())

        // Fails
        // lines <- []byte(s.Bytes())
        // lines <- s.Bytes()[:]
        // lines <- s.Bytes()
    }
    close(lines)
}()
```

The version above works properly, but if I just do `lines <- s.Bytes()` (or the other ones I tested), the data gets corrupted because Scanner.Bytes() is always returning the same slice, and I'm passing that slice through the channel, but it's being mutated while the workers are reading it.

My question is, what is the correct/idiomatic way to put `Scanner.Bytes()` on a channel to prevent this corruption?  The way I've posted above works, but it's fairly ugly IMHO, and the string hack is short, but it's really a terrible way to copy data.

Ultimately, I am using this method to read billions of lines of data, so if an extra `[]byte` copy can be removed, I'm all for it.  The work being done in the workers is slow (JSON Unmarshaling, etc), but the input scanner is a single thread, so I'm trying to get it to split lines as quickly as possible.

Comment: You can't use a buffer in one place and concurrently write to it in another without making a copy. There's no magic way to send a single buffer to multiple workers and have it contain different data. You can help make the _allocations_ more efficient with a free list or a `sync.Pool`, but there will always need to be a copy.

Comment: Thanks @JimB - I was not aware of sync.Pool, but I've tried it out and it's a pretty clever way to avoid extra allocations!  In my application, the copy() method was reducing performance from 450k lines/sec to 285k/s, but after testing these methods, I think it was simply due to resource contention during allocation.